# Firebase Callable Function: Response for preflight in invalid

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have created a Firebase callable function, with a simple text return, but am receiving an error when I call the function, both on local and on my deployed app.

The callable function is a simple function to return some text for now:

```
exports.getSomeInfo = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  return 'some info';
});
```

In my app I load the function with:

```
const getSomeInfo = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('getSomeInfo');
```

And call it in the app with:

```
getSomeInfo();
```

This produces an error of:

```
Failed to load https://us-central1-[project-ID].cloudfunctions.net/getSomeInfo: Response for preflight is invalid (redirect)
```

This error occurs when calling the function on local using `firebase serve` and on the deployed app.

Viewing the logs in the Firebase Console shows no logs or errors.

Other issues mention this could be a CORS issue, or an incorrect Firebase config. I've ensured the Firebase config is correct. And tried a few of the CORS solutions, but continue to get the error above.

Using Firebase@5.5.2.

What else could be causing this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As indicated in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#sending_back_the_result), for an HTTPS Callable function you need to **"return data that can be JSON encoded"**.

So if you do something like the following, it should work.

```
exports.getSomeInfo = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  return {result: 'some info'};
});
```

*Update: removed the `async`*

Comment: This could be part of the problem. I'm now thinking it's due to my app being setup as a SPA, with a redirect in `firebase.json` directing all routes to `index.html`. When the callable function is called, it hits the https endpoint and is going through a redirect.

Comment: I am not sure the client SDK calls the same domain than your project hosting domain when calling a Callable function. With regards to the URL you need to call for an HTTPS Cloud Function (i.e. https://us-central1-<project-id>.cloudfunctions.net/.....) I would say they are different and therefore your SPA settings don't impact the Callable Function.

Comment: I confirm, the Javascript SDK uses an URL with the following structure in order to call a Callable Cloud Function: https://us-central1-<project-id>.cloudfunctions.net/<function-name>

Comment: Can you confirm if sending back non-JSON formatted data results in the `Response for preflight is invalid (redirect)` error?

Comment: Actually your Function works as such but note that the Cloud Function test environment I used is in node.js 6. (So the function is written as `functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {})` and not as `functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {})` as you did).

Comment: Ok, I think we're making progress. I'm now getting `Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:5000' is therefore not allowed access.`. So I probably need to import the `cors` package?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181811/discussion-between-renaud-tarnec-and-brett-dewoody).

Comment: Hey guys, what was the solution of your problem @BrettDeWoody? Did you find out ? I meet the same issue as yours. But no answers anywhere else on the Web. My function sends data JSON ready, with no async, just like yours.

Comment: @JohanChouquet Hello Johan, you may ask a new question with all the details and in particular your code, which will allow us reproducing your problem.

Comment: Thanks @RenaudTarnec, I had exactly the same symptoms as Brett apparently. By digging more, I found a solution, and described on github as i feel that there's something to add to documentation somewhere (firebase doc ? or angularfire2 doc ?): (https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/2077). It might help some developers.

Answer (score 2):

April 2020, I just learned the hard way that callable functions have their module name prepended...

In index.js:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions')

// ...
exports.callable = require('./callable')
```

In callable.js:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
// ... other stuff
exports.myCloudFunction = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  // ...
```

The way to call this "myCloudFunction" from a JS client is to use its name, *prepended with its module name*, like this

```
const fn = firebase.functions().httpsCallable("callable-myCloudFunction")
fn().then(result => { //...
```

This is documented nowhere, as far as I have found, and, as others have mentioned, almost any error that occurs prior to actually executing the cloud function ends up mislabeled as a CORS error.

Comment: I'm on this page because after deployment, my cloud functions aren't working. In the functions emulator, however, everything was working fine without needing to prepend the module name. Any reason why the production server is different than the functions emulator?

Comment: @krummens - I've able to call functions successfully on and off (mostly off). I have been so flummoxed by https.onCall (and the associated docs, and the unclear half answers here and elsewhere) that I've given up using them entirely (including a recent test where, just like you, I thought I had it figured out in emulation only to fail with CORS in production).  Now, I've been relying (with success so far) on https.onRequest() functions using express middleware and some home-rolled caller infrastructure on the client.  This also was poorly described end-to-end anywhere online

Comment: If you want, ask a question about it and show me the link here, I'll post my solution.

Comment: Having spent a lot of time developing with `onCall`,  I'm hoping there is a simpler solution than rewriting for `onRequest`.

Comment: @krummens -best of luck and lmk if you get this sorted.  I'd happy use onCall (and bounty an answer) that can do a full stack round trip on both emulator and production, and remain working.  I think I have that with onRequest (the extra stuff I built around it is not too bad, IMO)

Comment: I guess if I can't get onCall working in the next day or so I'll post a question for onRequest

Answer (score 1):

After trying across 2 days a variety of refreshes/clean-ups and stuff with CORS, finally found it working after first deleting the function via Firebase console and then deploying the function.

In my case it seems the deployed version got corrupted somehow. It started yesterday when `deploy` for functions was getting stuck - it would hang and never exit - even though Firebase Status page said all is well.  It lasted all day, and I finally let it go to see if it will work today. I thought it was my code, but the `deploy` is back to working today.

Comment: It's strange, but I had to delete and upload the function again. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me a couple days ago. The problem was that when i ran `firebase deploy`the functions in my src directory were not being compiled. There were typescript errors which stopped it from compiling. You can see if it compiled by checking your lib folder and index.ts inside there I believe.